# Unable to understand the output of the program using printf weirdly

Tags: c, printf

I was working with some of the interview questions when I found this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 short int a=5;

 printf("%d"+1,a);    //does not give compiler error 

 return 0;
}
```

It prints the following:

```
d
```

I am unable to understand how the printf function works here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/381554/1233508 should clarify things.

Comment: it gives a warning though. i guess the `printf()` just wants the first argument, i.e. `+1`

Comment: Here `printf("%d"+1,a);` = `printf("d");`

Comment: i ran that http://ideone.com/Qb2blI

Comment: @Ani but how compiler works through it ?

Comment: @user3126632 , [Check this out](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-adding-integer-format-specifier/)!

Comment: what will printf ("%%%%") print and how

Comment: That will print `%%` . To print one `%` , you need two `%%` in your `printf`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's look at the first argument to the `printf()` call.

```
"%d" + 1
```

This points to the same thing as `ptr` does in the following code.

```
char *ptr = "%d";
ptr = ptr + 1;
```

So, what does it mean to increment a pointer? Well, we advance the pointer `sizeof(*ptr) * 1` bytes forward.

So, in memory we have:

```
%d\0
^^
||
|This is where ("%d" + 1) points to.
This is where ("%d") points to.
```

So, your code is more or less functionally equivalent to doing:

```
short int a = 5;
printf("d", a);
```

Which will evaluate and then ignore the extra function argument and print `d`.

---

**One more thing:** You're very close to causing undefined behavior in that code. `printf("%d", a)` is using the wrong format string. The correct format string for a `short int` is `"%hd"`.

You can find a full table of format strings [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: It's not a problem to print `short`s with `%d`. They're promoted to `int` anyway.

Comment: what does % operator in printf suggest the compiler to do

Comment: What happens for this
printf("%",a);

Comment: @user3126632: it is not a compiler instruction. `printf` is a simple function that scans its first argument, the format string, for sequences it recognizes. Read `man printf`.

Comment: Incrementing a pointer means to move it `1` position forward, not `sizeof(*ptr) * 1`. The latter expression is the number of bytes.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I intended that to mean that it moves it forward `sizeof(*ptr) * 1` bytes. Fixing with: `s/positions/bytes`. If you think there's a better way to word it, feel free to edit it in as well.

Answer (score 7):

`"%d" + 1` does pointer arithmetic, the compiler sees it as `"d"`, so

```
printf("%d"+1,a);
```

becomes:

```
printf("d", a);
```

You can see why it outputs `d` in your compiler.

As @sharth points out in the comment, the extra argument `a` here is evaluated and discarded.

Comment: It's not undefined behavior to pass extra arguments. It's only undefined if you pass too few. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3579752/47453

Comment: @sharth I did not know that. It's so nice to learn something new through answering ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is my answer based off @DCoder 's comment. `"%d"` is a pointer to the first character of the two character array `%d`. Incrementing this by one gives a pointer to `d`. The fact that there is a second argument now does not matter as the result of the expression `"%d"+1` is simply the character `d`. If you try adding `0` your output is `5` as expected. If you try adding `2`, there is no output as there is only `""` is being passed to `printf`.

Comment: "If you try adding 2" then the format is `""`.  If you try adding more than 2, it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `printf("%d"+1,a);` = `printf("d",a)`.

You are specifying `printf` to print from +1 position which is `"d"`, so `printf` will simply print `d` on screen.