# Printf function formatting wrt to different values.

Tags: c, printf

I was making a complex number calculator using struct, here is my printf function

```
printf("%d%c%di", sum.real, sign, sum.imag);
```

I can everything correct except one thing, when the sum.imag part is 1 or -1 ofcourse it prints out "1i" or "-1i" respectively, is there a way apart from using a lot of "if"s that i can format the printf function where if sum.imag is 1 or -1 it shouldn't print the value instead print just the "i"??

Comment: If sounds like you want to embed an `if` statement into the format string itself, which, as far as I know, isn't possible.

Comment: IMO, to achieve this, you don't need `lot of "if"s`... single `if..else` based on `sum.imag ` will do.

Comment: As @SouravGhosh said you could use 1 if like `if(sum.imag == 1 || sum.imag == -1 ) printf("%d%ci", sum.real, sign); else printf("%d%c%di", sum.real, sign, sum.imag);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with your format string; you'll have to use an if statement:

```
if (sum.imag == 1 || sum.imag == -1) {
    printf("%d%ci", sum.real, sign);
} else {
    printf("%d%c%di", sum.real, sign, sum.imag);
}
```

Alternatively you could use a ternary expression for the format string, but this would be a quite a bit more unreadable, and is actually undefined behaviour although it should work on most modern compilers, although they will produce a warning about the (sometimes) unused argument. You can read more about this on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578970/passing-too-many-arguments-to-printf).

```
printf((sum.imag == 1 || sum.imag == -1) ? "%d%ci" : "%d%c%di"), sum.real, sign, sum.imag);
```

Comment: the second example is undefined behaviour.

Comment: if sum.imag is 1 or -1 your printf looks like `printf("%d%ci", sum.real, sign, sum.imag);`, so you have only 2 format specifier, but 3 parameters, which is undefined behaviour. there is also a `)` too much in this line.

Comment: Sure. But on most modern compilers it will give a warning but still work as expected. I've updated the answer to mention that this is undefined behaviour and included a link to a question about extra `printf` arguments.