# Why is the following program valid and why does it output "worldhello"?

Tags: c

What is the output of the following program?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("hello",printf("world"));
}
```

Comment: Actually, looking at [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) I think it is valid. *If there are more arguments than required by format, the extraneous arguments are evaluated and ignored*

Comment: @Kevin It is actually valid and I removed my comment saying it is not..

Comment: @EugeneSh. so did I :)

Comment: for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578970/passing-too-many-arguments-to-printf

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for lots of reasons why `void main()` is dubious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> If there are fewer arguments than required by format, the behavior is
>   undefined. If there are more arguments than required by format, the
>   extraneous arguments are **evaluated** and ignored.

The output of the program is:

```
worldhello
```

The argument of the first `printf` is:
   `printf("world")`

Since the argument is a function, the function will be called producing word:

```
word
```

Then first `printf` will print `hello`. Those prints together will give you:

```
worldhello
```

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf(" hello! %d",printf("world"));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
world hello! 5
```

If `printf` is successful the total number of characters written is returned. On failure, a negative number is returned.

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` function which prints `world` runs first as `C` cannot execute the first `printf` until all of its arguments have been evaluated (as it evaluates extra arguments supplied before the main one) meaning that it waits for `'world'` to be printed before printing `'hello'`.